# Why i cant disable false button2 and the red x in the new Form?

Tags: c#

Solved:

In Form1 i did:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cl = new ChangeLink();
            cl.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
            DialogResult dr = cl.ShowDialog(this);
            if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                cl.Close();
            }
            else if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {    
                    label4.Text = cl.getText();
                    mainUrl = cl.getText();
                    if (!LocalyKeyWords.ContainsKey(mainUrl))
                    {
                        newUrl = true;
                        KeysValuesUpdate();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newUrl = false;
                        KeysValuesUpdate();
                    }
                    OptionsDB.set_changeWebSite(cl.getText());
                    cl.Close();
            } 


        }
```

Checking if the Value the text the user enter in the new Form textBox exist or ont in the List. If exist show the new Form regular the user can cancel or close the form.
If the text from the new Form is not exist in the List show the new Form this time the button2 is false and also the ControlBox is false.

In the new Form i needed to check if the Form1.newUrl is true in the constructor not in the button1 click event. Since the button click event is fire up after i click the button. I wanted that the check wil be when the new Form is show up.

```
if (Form1.newUrl == true)
            {
                button2.Enabled = false;
                this.ControlBox = false;
                DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                Form1.newUrl = false;
            }
```

This is in the new Form constructor.

In any case its now working. 
Thanks.

Comment: Where are you declaring and creating Form1?

Comment: Form1 is the main form. cl is the new form wich is ChangeLink. cl = new ChangeLink() this is the Form with the button2 and red x i cant disable.

Comment: And in this new form the ChangeLink im using the bool variabl from Form1 . In Form1 i did that newUrl is a public static.